# Dynamically making javascript array of object value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arrays

We can create a javascript array like bellow

```
    var array = { name:"jhon", desg:"manager" };
```

We can send the object directly as data with an $ajax request, and all value can be accessed using $_POST array. Ex : $_POST['name'] will return 'jhon'.

Now I have a for loop where I want to make the array dynamic.
Something like :

```
    for(var i=0; i<8; i++){
        array.push(a+id:"me"+id);
    }
```

Now I will send array in $ajax request and in request handler I will be able to retrieve data in $_POST array. Ex : $_POST['a0'] will return 'me0'.

I tried many way but failed, do you have any way to solve this.

Comment: first of all that is an `object` not an array.

Comment: Thanks, for clarification. I just read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should clear your mind, that is an `object` not an array.

Try something like bellow. I am using variable `data` instead of `array`.

```
var data = {}; //creating a blank object

for(var i=0; i<8; i++){
    data['a'+id] = me+'id';
}
```

In your PHP you will get content in `$_POST` variable, so `$_POST['a0']` will return you 'me0'

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
array[a+id] = "me"+id;
```

(Note that a better name would be "object" rather than an "array".)